# How to pass the(serverClients[i].read() to byte array on ESP8266

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, esp8266

In a sketch of Arduino there is an example WiFi Telnet To Serial with ESP8266. There is a piece of code that is used to receive data from a client:

```
 //check clients for data
 for(i = 0; i < MAX_SRV_CLIENTS; i++){
   if (serverClients[i] && serverClients[i].connected()){
     if(serverClients[i].available()){
    //get data from the telnet client and push it to the UART
     while(serverClients[i].available()) 
        Serial.write(serverClients[i].read());
   }
  }
 }
```

This data is sent to the console or the serial port, but I need to capture that data and store it in a byte array:

```
byte bufferMSGfromCliente[1024]
```

How to do it?

Comment: what did you already attempt and what went wrong? It looks like you problem has nothing to do with esp. Make simple console PC application which reads user inputs and fills in data into such buffer to "debug" such "complicated" "algorithm".

Answer (score 1):

Its not c++ but you might be able to use a processing sketch. The syntax is very close to arduino so it should be familiar.

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;  // The serial port

void setup() {
  // List all the available serial ports
  printArray(Serial.list());
  // Open the port you are using at the rate you want:
  myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 9600);
}

void draw() {
    int i = 0;
    byte[] bufferMSGfromCliente = new byte[1024];
    while (myPort.available() > 0) {
        int inByte = myPort.read();
        if(i > 1024)
        {
            i = 0;
        }
        bufferMSGfromCliente[i] = inByte;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to write it to another Serial port? Here you write it on the same Serial port as your Serial Monitor.
Best would be to store serverClients[i].read() into a Byte and then Serial.println(Byte) to see what the information is.
After that, ask yourself:
1. What Serial port will this information be sent to, what is the destination?
2. How can I confirm that information is sent succesfully and has the ability to be debugged.

Also, use Serial.flush() to make sure the Serial.write function completes. Eventhough it says ''flush'', the function in Arduino IDE waits for the Serial write function to be completed.